# java jdbc:sqlite no suitable driver. classpath issues i think

Tags: java, sqlite, classpath

I'm running ubuntu. I installed sqlite3 and java via the synaptic package manager, and downloaded the sqlitejdbc-v056 jar.

My sqlite is working fine. I've written some java code that compiles, but wont run. I used ant to compile the stuff and that worked fine once i put the jar in the same place as build.xml.

When i try to run the program (by saying java program) it says: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:test.db

here's some of the offending code:

```
 Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
```

From what I've read thus far it's probably a problem with my classpath, i'm not really sure how to fix it though. here's what i've tried:

1. put the .jar in the same directory as my compiled program main stuff
2. put the .jar in the same directory as my compiled class that uses the sql stuff
3. tried using the -classpath option when calling java from the terminal. I tried this with relative addressing first, then an absolute path
4. 3 but with wildcards, ie .../*.jar
5. sudo gedit /etc/environment. there was no CLASSPATH so i put this in: CLASSPATH="*.jar:/home/sheena/Java/lib/*.jar:.:.*.jar:/home/sheena/Java/lib/"

I feel like i'm out of options.

on a separate but related note, i also really struggled to get javac to see the jar while i was compiling, i couldn't get the ant stuff about the classpath right either. This part isn't as urgent as the stuff above but here's a little bit of build.xml:

```
<path id="files-classpath">  
    <fileset dir="lib/" >  
        <include name="*.jar"/>  
    </fileset>  
</path>
```

...

those are just some of the things i tried.

Any ideas would be much appreciated, the internet has surprisingly little info on this topic from what i can see...

Comment: The driver isn't packaged in more than one jar file is it? On your compile time path you have "*.jar" - wildcards don't work with the -classpath argument to java, so you may have to add all jars in that directory manually to the -classpath argument.

Comment: I think the connection string format is wrong. Examples I've seen are structured as jdbc:sqlite:/<path to db> i.e. jdbc:sqlite:/C:/tools/SQLite/cdr.db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running it like this:

```
java -classpath ".:sqlite-jdbc-v056.jar" ProgramName
```

the ".:" is very important (i wasn't sure if your tried that or not from your description). also i just guessed what the name of your .jar is, but obviously change it to reflect the actual name.